# Gradle second build fails after modifying styles.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've migrated my project to use Gradle (using the old Android project structure).
Recently I have upgraded Android Studio to v0.2, which forced me to use android gradle plugin v0.5.
I'm able to build my project using any of the flavours I have defined, either on debug/release.

Something goes wrong for me using the following scenario:

- Execute gradlew clean
- Execute gradlew assembleTestenvDebug
- Gradle output at this point:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

- Modify **any** value in styles.xml file
- Execute gradlew assembleTestenvDebug (again)
- Gradle output at this point:

> /Users/myuser/Project/src/com/namespace/project/views/SomeCustomView.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
>               mSize = arr.getInt(R.styleable.SomeCustomView_some_custom_styleable, 0);

Gradle now complains on every custom xml attribute I have declared in attrs.xml.
This is driving me nuts as I have to clean & rebuild my project every single time I modify styles.xml

PLEASE help me out.

Thanks!

My project structure:

```
- Project
- . AndroidManifest.xml
- . assets/
- . build/
- . build.gradle
- . gen/
- . gradle/
- . gradle.properties
- . gradlew
- . libs (includes .jar files)
- . modules
- . . library_projectA
- . . library_projectB
- . out
- . project.properties
- . res

- . res_testenv
- . . values
- . . . strings.xml

- . res_prodenv
- . . values
- . . . strings.xml

- . settings.gradle
- . src/
- . . com/
- . . . namespace/
- . . . . android/
```

build.gradle in project dir:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':modules:libprojectA')
    compile project(':modules:libprojectB')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            runProguard false
        }

        alphaRelease {
            runProguard false
            zipAlign true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        testenv {}
        prodenv {}
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        }

        testenv {}
        prodenv {}
    }

    android.sourceSets.testenv {
        res.srcDirs = ['res_test']
    }

    android.sourceSets.prodenv {
        res.srcDirs = ['res_prod']
    }
}

if (project.hasProperty('storeFile') && project.hasProperty('storePassword') &&
        project.hasProperty('keyAlias') && project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(storeFile)
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
}
```

and build.gradle file for each of the library projects:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Attached stacktrace:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestenvDebug'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
>       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:95)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
>       at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>       ... 70 more

Comment: are you modifying `style.xml` in `res`, or another folder like `res_flavor1`?

Comment: @Joe - I'm modifying res/values/styles.xml from the main project directory, not any flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 0.5.4 which is available now.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I have a theory, but I could be wrong.

Looking at the [user
guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) I don't
see any mention of adding custom sourceSets directly. This might mean that the
build system doesn't detect changes on sourceSets like `testenv` unless it's a
part of a flavor or a buildType.

What I would try is defining your environment as a flavor group. Not sure about
your specific requirements, but it might look something like this:

```
flavorGroups "environment", "flavors"
productFlavors {
    testenv { 
        flavorGroup "environment"
    }

    prodenv {
        flavorGroup "environment"
    }

    flavorA {
        flavorGroup "flavors"
        ...
    }

    flavorB {
        flavorGroup "flavors"
        ...
    }
```

This is assuming you need a build that can be composed of these two, such as
`app-flavor1-testenv-debug.apk`. Just a thought though, I haven't tested it.

Also, a suggestion, if you get this working I would recommend migrating to the new layout. That way you can rely on the conventions of `src/main/res` merging with `src/testenv/res` and `src/debug/res` if they exist, without even having to mention them in `build.gradle`.

Comment: also, please review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly

Comment: ah, got it. Yeah, I was wondering about all the flavors :-). We use 4 in our project, along with an API key that's different for release signed builds as it is for debug, so we benefited greatly from the new layout.

Comment: that said, I'm not sure how flavors are implemented but the default value of `testenv.srcDirs` might include `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs`, which would be overwritten if it's set to only `['res_test']`. Try it with `res.srcDirs += 'res_test'`.