# get App name in gradle.build

Tags: android, gradle

Hi I have a common module for two apps,and I want to add a dependency in that common module if I am running on a certain app,I tried the code below,but that didn't work.

```
 if (project.getName() == 'MyApp')
    {
        compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.49.5'
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simple answer is you can't.  If your shared module has any code that requires React Native then your code won't compile.  If your shared module doesn't have any React Native code then you don't need the dependency. You can put that dependency in your non-shared module that uses React Native.

Comment: The problem was that I was creating ReactFragment so I modified my Class that extend Application class,so moving the dependency or class is a problem,but thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410995/conditional-dependencies-with-gradle-is-it-possible) Might be helpful for you. It sounds like creating different product flavors is an option for creating dependency conditions.

Update:

Adding examples of productFlavors from [android studio documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)

```
android {
    ...


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }


    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
            versionCode 20
         }


         flavor2 {
             applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
             minSdkVersion 14
         }
    }
}

dependencies {
    flavor1Compile "..."
    ...
    flavor2Compile “...”
}
```

If this isn’t sufficient for your needs you could always have your dependencies rely on [external project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html), an example from the above post I mentioned is here:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android"+(project.ext.has("leakCanary")?"":"-no-op")+":1.3.1"
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.