# Upload Free App for specific countries

Tags: android, google-play

I published a paid App in Google play store, but i need the same App to be available free for specific countries, is this possible and how to do it ?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: yes i marked your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, you should have a look at application flavors. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly) a post that covers that topic.

In short, you create two different package names so that you can generate two different signed apk files to publish to Google Play. In your case, that would be your paid app and your free app. The country configuration would be done in the Google Play developer console, as you probably know.

This is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) covering the subject.