# Android onClickListener not fired in custom flavor

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-productflavors

**EDITED**

Thanks to all that voted me negative without trying help. That is really useful.

This main problem was I had 2 same fragments, one in main and other in the premium flavor. So the system was loading always the fragment stored in main and because of that the button listener is never called.

You can solve it removing the fragment from main path and create the fragment in every flavor you have, by this way the proper fragment will be selected

> If you want to have a different version of the same class in the two
>   flavor you'll need to create it in both flavors and remove it from main.
>
> ```
> src/flavor1/java/com/foo/A.java
>
> src/flavor2/java/com/foo/A.java
> ```
>
> And then your code in `src/main/java` can do:
>
> ```
> import com.foo.A
> ```
>
> depending on the flavor selected, the right version of `com.foo.A` is
>   used.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm trying to set a button in a "premium" flavor that is not shown in the main flavor. The problem is the button is shown in the UI, but the onClickListener is never fired.

My structure is the following:

I have an activity that contains a fragment. The activity is unique for all flavor, but the fragment is going to change depends of the flavor. One of that flavor contains a button that is not shown in the main flavor. When tap on that button, nothing happens.

Here is the code related:

The activity xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".activities.ConfigurationActivity">

<ImageView
        ...
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/configurationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity code is:

```
package com.abc.project.activities;
public class ConfigurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment confFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

        confFragment = new ConfigurationFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.configurationFragment, confFragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

The **main fragment** xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ...
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="com.abc.project.fragments.ConfigurationFragment">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Main fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The **main fragment** code is:

```
package com.abc.project.fragments;
public class ConfigurationFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuration, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The **premium fragment** xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ...
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="com.abc.project.premium.fragments.ConfigurationFragment">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Premium fragment!"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/premiumButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button premium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the **premium fragment** code is:

```
package com.abc.project.premium.fragments;
public class ConfigurationFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button premiumButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuration, container, false);

        premiumButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.premiumButton);
        premiumButton.setOnClickListener(premiumOnClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener premiumOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //THIS CODE NEVER IS FIRED
        }
    };
}
```

So, the "premium" xml is showed properly, but the button does not fire the onClickListener.

Anyone knows why is that happening?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kemmitorz.

Comment: Is there 2 classes with same `ConfigurationFragment` name?

Comment: Yes, but in different packages. One in the package related to the main favor, the other one in the package related to the premium flavor

Comment: Use view.getId() inside onclick event

Comment: @PatelJaimin the onclick event is not fired so I cannot use the view.getId() inside it

Comment: How do you control what fragment class should be used? It seems your premium fragment class is never called.

Comment: @Ircover you can see in the premium xml the context defined is the premium package that contains the premium fragment class. So I supposed that it would use the proper fragment class, but it is not true. Then, is there a way to use that specific fragment class instead of the main fragment class?

Comment: Try to find solution here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment need to implement with `View.OnClickListener`

```
 public class InputFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

then change your code as below

```
 onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

 btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

 btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

 switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:

        //HERE YOU CAN PERFORM YOUR ACTION
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:

[Android Studio build flavors - How to have same source files in diverse flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016283/android-studio-build-flavors-how-to-have-same-source-files-in-diverse-flavors)

> If you want to have a different version of the same class in the two
>   flavor you'll need to create it in both flavors and remove it from main.
>
> ```
> src/flavor1/java/com/foo/A.java
>
> src/flavor2/java/com/foo/A.java
> ```
>
> And then your code in `src/main/java` can do:
>
> ```
> import com.foo.A
> ```
>
> depending on the flavor selected, the right version of `com.foo.A` is
>   used.