# What's the uiautomator version that will support Android SDK Level 16?

Tags: android, user-interface, icalendar, android-uiautomator

The UiAutomator v2.+ version supports only SDK level 18+ and according to documentation uiautomator shipped first with SDK Level 16.
I need a way to include that version in my gradle file rather than v2.1.1.
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'

Comment: you should comment if suggested solution resolved the problem. If yes, please accept answer so other can benefit as well. Cheers

Comment: As it arrived many months after the questions I must have overlooked it. No, it does not solve my problem. I have addressed the problem using build flavors.

Comment: Please describe in answers how you did it, so others can benefit. Thanks :)

Comment: As the approach suggested in the answer seemed not viable I ended up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly

Answer (score 2):

Add this specific AndroidManifest.xml into **androidTest** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="your.package">

    <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>

</manifest>
```

Trick here is done with:

```
tools:overrideLibrary marker
```

> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to
>   override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent
>   than that application's minimum SDK version. Without such a marker,
>   the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select
>   which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

Comment: studio already gives suggestion for this workaround. This is not proper answer.