# How to override the android library class

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some android project,most of them use the same code,only the picture and server api is different. So I fetch the common code to common library,named "common-library", and my project named "wch".

In the common-library has a "GlobalConstant.java",

[image]

each project is different. So my issue is how to override the GlobalConstant class in the "wch" project?

Comment: Have you included "common-library" module in your "wch" project?

Comment: I would place a method in a class like the application context class which returns an instance of the GlobalConstant class. Then you can extend this application context in your app project and return an other impl. of GlobalConstants.

Comment: yes,I included the "common-library" module in "wch" project.

Comment: I tried create a GlobalConstant class in the "wch" project,I think when Android Sutdio complie the project will replace the common-library GlobalConstant class use "wch" GlobalConstant.It's a pity,it's output error: "com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/bdb/lot/common/library/global/GlobalConstants"

Answer (score 0):

You could use Build Flavors.

Configure the folder structure correctly ([see this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly)) then you can just use a separate `GlobalConstants` class for each flavor.