# Exclude code segment depending on flavor

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a lot of flavors, and I want only specific flavors to include a certain code segment. More specifically, I want to use a 3rd party library and add that library's init code only in specific flavors.

```
public class MainApplication
    extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    //The library is only included in the build of specific flavors, so having this code in other flavors will not compile
    //I want the following code only to be included in the flavors that include the library
    SomeLibrary.init();

    //other code that is relevant for all flavors
    ...

}}
```

Answer (score 6):

### A) Use reflection

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_THE_CRAZY_LIB", "false"
}
```

```
productFlavors {
    crazyFlavor {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_THE_CRAZY_LIB", "true"
        //... all the other things in this flavor
    }
}
```

then in your `Application`

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (BuildConfig.USE_THE_CRAZY_LIB) {
            Method method = clazz.getMethod("init", SomeLibrary.class);
            Object o = method.invoke(null, args);
        }

    }
}
```

---

### B) Use two different versions of the same class for two different flavors

*(more information on that approach e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746755/1993204))*

1. For the other flavor (in `src/otherFlavor/java`):

   ```
   public class FlavorController {
       public static void init(){
       }
   }
   ```
2. For your flavor (in `src/crazyFlavor/java`):

   ```
   public class FlavorController {
       public static void init(){
           SomeLibrary.init();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your `Application`:

   ```
   public class MainApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           FlavorController.init();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm familiar with option B. I was hoping to avoid code duplication in all flavors.

Comment: You don't really have much choice. Either this or reflection. Other solutions will fail in compile time.

Comment: @RotemMatityahu did I answer your question? Feel free to accept the answer then

Comment: @BartekLipinski hi, I know this is a old question but do you know if the excluded library will still be compiled and exists in a flavor that don't implement it? Or if there's a better way to do it now

Comment: @AndersonVanzo if you choose option B, and properly import the dependency (just for the flavor), the library will not be included for any other flavor. Example of flavor-specific gradle dependency: `crazyFlavorImplementation 'com.included.library:artifact:4.8.15'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gradle to solve this issue by using with custom configurations.

Use this pattern to create custom configurations this line to your build.gradle file ,

```
configurations {
    prodFlavBuildTypeCompile
}

dependencies {
    prodFlavBuildTypeCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

For example , My app flavours are **free** and **paid** with build types **dev** and **prod**

```
configurations {
    freeDevCompile
    freeProdCompile
}

dependencies {
    freeDevCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

And in the main folder keep Application with common code.

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And use the implementation code in each product flavours.

```
public class ApplicationImpl extends BaseApp {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SomeLibrary.init();
    }
}
```

code for other flavours,

```
public class ApplicationImpl extends BaseApp {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // code for flavour 2
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, I have a lot of flavors and I want to avoid code duplication.