# How should I release multiple flavours of my Android app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors

I've already released an Android app in the Play Store. How should I release multiple flavours, like a demo version vs. a full version?

Can the installation of a full version override an already installed demo version?

Comment: check this link http://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly

Comment: you can't override one app with another. There are 2 ways: 1) 2 different apps, which won't override each other, and can be installed simultaneously. 2) 1 app, which will have *upgrade to full* feature as an in-app purchase. This way you have to store if user has purchased full, or not.    But you can't replace one app with another, if they have different packages

Comment: You could maybe make the free app check whether the full app is installed and then show a message that the free app should be uninstalled and then starts the full app, maybe with two buttons, one that starts the full app, one that takes you to the app settings for uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

To make is possible to install apps built from different flavors simultaneously you need to set different `applicationId` to them.

Something like:

```
productFlavors {
    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
    }
    full {
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
    }
}
```