# Using my custom class in build variants

Tags: android, android-activity, android-build, android-build-flavors

I have created 4 different flavours in build variants in my app.
I have added version and suffix in the configuration in my app's **build.gradle.**. Below is the code:

```
productFlavors {
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [application: ".utils.Application"]
    }

    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [application: ".utils.Application"]
    }


    dev {

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [application: ".utils.Application"]
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    uat {
        applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [application: ".utils.Application"]
    }
}
```

In my app, I use a file **APIAddresses.java** for selecting the URLs to hit according to the environment.
Is there any way I can use only this file out of all the source code in **build.gradle** only to configure URLs for build variants?

May be create different copies of this file for each build variant, something similar to this.

```
productFlavors {
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        APIAddresses_QA
    }

    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        APIAddresses_DEMO
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add your different java file in flavor based folder structure and you can used it accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Build Flavors - Structuring source folders and build.gradle correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use one version of your file APIAddresses.java for all your variants.

In your build.gradle, add

```
flavorDimensions "main"
```

Put your APIAddresses.java file in the app\src\main directory.

In your code, you can then generate different URLs for each variant using the variable

`BuildConfig.FLAVOR`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add lot of `if-else` conditions in your classes, you can add new `buildConfigField` to each flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://server1.com"'
    }

    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://server2.com"'
    }

    ...
}
```

After that you can call `BuildConfig.SERVER_URL` on Java side, and according to each flavor, it should return proper URL in my example