# This same class for two different product flavor

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I have 2 product flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    first{}
    second{}
}
```

and I have a class `Http` with constant value like on screen:

[image]

My problem is:

If I have set build `first`, I want `Http` class with `CODE = 2000`
but if I have set build `second` I want `Http` class with `CODE = 1000`

I have seen such a project which looked like : repo(first) and after change
build repo(second) and class http was different depending on the current build, but can't replicate it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two copies of your `Http` class, one in `src/first/com.androidapp.testproject/repo` and the other one in `src/second/com.androidapp.testproject/repo`, and remove the copy from `src/main/...`.

The first version of your class in `src/first/...` will get built for your flavor `first`, and the one in `src/second/...` will get built for your flavor `second`. Of course, you have to adjust the value for `CODE` in the appropriate copy of your classes.

See the following answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746755/3286819

Comment: please, could you help me with my question? I have a similar problem, but I'm getting error in second flavor because I'm using android annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715835/androidannotation-with-2-productflavors

Comment: @Ladessa I've just seen your comment and question post. Glad that you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

If your classes are the same but the only difference is the constant, then you do not need to duplicate the code and all you need to do is create gradle constants that you access via the `BuildConfig` class:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        buildConfigField 'int', 'CODE', '1000'
    }

    flavor2 {
        buildConfigField 'int', 'CODE', '2000'
    }
}
```

Then you would use

```
BuildConfig.CODE
```

in your HTTP calls, that would hold 1000 or 2000 depending on the flavor.

Comment: Agree. This would be a better solution than mine for such a simple case. In case you need a more complex solution (e.g. different methods depending on your flavor) then my solution will be the way to go.