# Using a different class for an Intent based on the product flavor

Tags: android, android-activity, android-productflavors

We are currently working with [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to create differing apps with the same codebase. I've run into this scenario:

I have two Apps, **App A** and **App B**. Inside `src/main`, so in both flavors' scopes, I have an activity called `Start_Activity`. From `Start_Activity`, I want to move to either `A_Activity` or `B_Activity`, based on which app we're in. `A_Activity` and `B_Activity` are only in the scope of their respective flavors.

What's the best way of attempting this? I don't want to move `Start_Activity` into the separate flavors, since that'd defeat the point of reusing code.

Can I resolve an activity class for an `Intent` from ressource files or from the manifest? Or can I only create a class with same-named-constants that exists in each flavor?

**Edit**

I neglected to mention that I specifically don't want to use a method where the activities share the same name and only exist in the scope of their respective flavors (for example, renaming both `A_Activity` and `B_Activity` to `X_Activity`).

I don't want to use this because I could run into the situation where I have **App C** that also wants to use `A_Activity`. Using this method, I'd have to have the `A_Activity` file in both flavors for **App A** and **App C**, which is not clean enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746755/7325737

"If you want to have a different version of the same class in the two flavor you'll need to create it in both flavors.

```
src/flavor1/java/com/foo/A.java
src/flavor2/java/com/foo/A.java
```

And then your code in src/main/java can do

```
import com.foo.A
```

depending on the flavor selected, the right version of com.foo.A is used."

I think this should help you!

Comment: Thank you Hani! While this is definitely correct, I should've mentioned that I specifically don't want to use this method, because I also could run into the situation where I have **App C** that also wants to use `A_Activity`. Using your method, I'd have to have the `A_Activity` file in both flavors for **App A** and **App C**, which is not clean enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

In `Start_Activity` you can create the start intent via [Intent.parseUri(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#parseUri(java.lang.String,%20int)) which can be loaded from a config file or a string resource

Comment: How can I use a URI for activities inside my app? Do I have to declare the URI in the app's manifest?

Comment: I used this method and it works! Would you mind adding an example to be more clear to other people looking for the answer? Or can I edit an example into your answer?